# Simple solution for HTML/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Excuse my ignorance if this is easily answered!

Based on content sliders using `<ul>` with individual `<li>` for slides...Should this code work?

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li> <script type ="text/javascript" src="locationofjscontent1")</li>
    <li> <script type ="text/javascript" src="locationofjscontent2")</li>
    <li> <script type ="text/javascript" src="locationofjscontent3")</li>
</ul>
```

Currently using a jQuery slider (boxslider) and within the different slides (max 3) I am trying to insert an extrnal javascript/jquery slider.

Slider works, but content only shows in first slide and not the others.

Any help greatly received!

Thanks

Comment: <li> <script type ="text/javascript" src="locationofjscontent1")</li>

Did you forget to close the tag script?

Comment: Sorry, yes they are closed... but it's not working - is there any other method to include them?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you want to close the `<script>` tags?

```
<li><script src="file.js"></script></li>
```

Though, I'm going to suggest you really don't do this as it's bad practice to litter script tags amongst your HTML. Ideally they should all be placed at the bottom of your code before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Sorry, yes they are closed... but it's not working - is there any other method to include them?

Comment: Without knowing what any of the code does, I don't think anyone can help out.

Comment: OK, but in princple, can you input scripts like that in to content sliders?

Comment: Why would you wanna do that? Those scripts will all be executed on the initial loading of the page. So you could as well just include all the scripts at the end of your HTML, like Todd said.

Comment: Hi, thanks for input - the scripts input an animated image with rollover pop outs, so they need to be in the slider.

Comment: They don't need to be, you just haven't abstracted the DOM correctly with selectors.

Comment: Thanks for response Todd - is there any simple guides on how I might do this?

Comment: I could advise, but without knowing/seeing what's inside the script tags - I can't help out.

Comment: the script points to more JS which uses document.write among other things to input, how would I include instead of the script link? what tags would need to be around it?

Comment: It's not as simple as includes and links to things. You need to decouple your JS from your HTML so the two are standalone.

Comment: OK, for example:

`document.write('<script type="text/javascript"> var section = "image1"; </script>');document.write('<div id="content"></div>');document.write('<script src="123domain/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');document.write('<script src="123domain/more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');`

Comment: that is what the script in each `<li>` is pointing to. Thanks for support so far Todd :)

Comment: So each script tag contains all that?

Comment: Yes, I would be inputting two of these, max three. Any chance we could use online chat one here?

Comment: Drop me an email, will be easier to explain: toddmotto.com/contact